# Formatting JSON response in C# Webapi using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to format the JSON response on the get() method

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    EmployeeDatabaseEntities entities = new EmployeeDatabaseEntities();
    var result = from e in entities.Employees
                 select new
                 {
                     name = e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName,
                     gender = e.Gender,
                     salary = e.Salary
                 };

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
        new
        {
            employees = new
            {
                name = result.Select(e => e.name),
                gender = result.Select(e => e.gender),
                salary = result.Select(e => e.salary)
            }
        });
}
```

However I am getting errors when trying to get.

```
"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.",
```

Comment: You need to do it the other way around, i.e `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCodes.OK, result.Select(x => new { name = x.name; gender = x.gender; salary = x.salary });`, this will return a JSON string along the lines of `[ { "name": "Jon Doe", "gender": "Not specified", "salary": 1500 }. { ... } ]`

Comment: The way you build your object is weird to say the least. `employees` is one object not a list. With 3 properties: `name` the list of every name in the result, gender and salary are the same.singular propereties name holding List of value. Now you have 3 list with nothing that connect a particular name with gender or salary. Why are you not returning result, directly?

Comment: I will also do simple debugging. Like adding a `ToList()` at the end of that result linQ query. Just to be sure that the error is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and it is kind of silly. It has to do with the single quote that I used to concat

OK

```
name = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,
```

Not Ok

```
name = e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName,
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to serialize an IQueryable query. Instead why don't you try this:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
        new
        {
            employees = result.Select(e => new  {
              name = e.name,
              gender = e.gender,
              salary = e.salary
            }).ToList()
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return the json in the same structure that your code has.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    EmployeeDatabaseEntities entities = new EmployeeDatabaseEntities();

    dynamic res = new {
            employees = new {
                // Typo - do not copy
                names = entities.Employees.Select(e=> e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName),
                genders = entities.Employees.Select(e => e.Gender),
                salaries = entities.Employees.Select(e => e.Salary)
            }
        });        
    return Ok(res);
}
```

I wonder why you don't send the json in the simple item>properties structure like:

```
dynamic res2 = entities.Employees.Select(e=> new { 
    // Typo - do not copy
    name = e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName, 
    gender = e.Gender, 
    salary = e.Salary, 
 });
return Ok(res2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is because of ' ' you can simple update your code like:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
            EmployeeDatabaseEntities entities = new EmployeeDatabaseEntities();
            var result = from e in entities.Clients
                         select new
                         {
                              name = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,
                              gender = e.Gender,
                              salary = e.Salary
                         };
    
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { employees=result });
}
```